# Is it possible to launch a VM's GUI from the command line with KVM without a desktop environment on host

Tags: virtualization, linux-kvm

Just did a fresh install of Arch Linux.

I will be running several VM's with KVM.

Is it possible to launch the VM's GUI from the the command line without a desktop environment such as gnome?

Comment: You don't want gnome/other on the host or the guest?

Comment: On the guest yes. But not on the host.